# abbreviate class/package? path to variable? in java

Tags: java, package, classpath

I don't exactly know what its called what I'm looking for but to explain…

When I have two classes of the same name but in different packages I want to keep them apart. But I don't want to type the fully qualified package name the whole time. So I have:

```
bar;
insanelylongpackagepath.stack.flow.bar;
```

can I say something like

```
easy = insanelylongpackagepath.stack.flow.;
```

and then reach to `bar` by simply

```
easy.bar;
```

Comment: There is no simple way to do this, though the use of aliases have been proposed before.  It is far better to give class unique names to avoid this sort of confusion.

Comment: this is just the beginning of your trouble if you have two public classes with the same name:) just don't do it. (unless they are from 3rd party and out of your control)

Comment: Okay, I thought C# did have this aliasing, correct? You're right, but I'm trying to marshall objects to xml and they're the same name as my object classes. Guess I will rename them.